# ant build.xml target to check for debug code

Tags: ant

When debugging it's quite common for me to use things such as Zend_Debug and die() in the PHP to locate an issue. Occasionally I forget to take these out before committing my code. So I was wondering...

How do I write an **ant build.xml** target which checks all the files in my application for specific strings and fails if they have been found?

Basically, I'm after a reverse `grep` command which fails when it finds a string.

Any ideas?

Also, given my *build.xml* file looks like this (I've removed most of my targets to make it short), how do I make it work?
I don't know how **ant** works, so I'm after a 'drop-in' solution or good instructions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="API" default="build" basedir=".">
    <property name="source"  value="application"/>

    <target name="build" depends="prepare,lint,phpcpd,phpdox,phpunit,phpcb"/>

    <target name="clean" description="Cleanup build artifacts">
        <delete dir="${basedir}/build/api"/>
    </target>

    <target name="lint">
        <apply executable="php" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="-l" />
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/${source}">
                <include name="**/*.php" />
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/tests">
                <include name="**/*.php" />
            </fileset>
        </apply>
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the `lint` target (after the `apply` element) add

```
<fileset id="die-files" dir="${basedir}/${source}">
    <include name="**/*.php" />
    <contains text="die()"/>
</fileset>
<fail message="The following files contain "die()": ${ant.refid:die-files}">
    <condition>
        <resourcecount when="greater" count="0" refid="die-files"/>
    </condition>
</fail>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use ant-contrib than:

```
<for param="file">
  <path>
    <fileset dir="/path/to/application/"/>
  </path>
  <sequential>
    <if>
      <contains string="@{file}" substring="bad elements"/>
      <then>
        <fail>warning! substring is present in directory</fail>
      </then>
    </if>
  </sequential>
</for>
```

Comment: Thanks :) How do I actually use that in my build.xml file? See the edits I've made to the original question.

Comment: - create a target: <target name="grep_my_project"><for param="file"........"</for></target> and add target's name to depends of "build" target

Comment: I got a weird error with this, so I went with the other solution. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I think that this weird error is present because you haven't ant-contrib. However, solution of tom-howard is much better than mine